# Node.js file not found

Tags: html, node.js

I'm using Node.exe in the following file structure

```
Node/
  node.exe
  index.js
  /view
     index.html
```

When running the following code:

```
  var html;
  fs.readFileSync('/view/index.html', function(err, data) { 
    if(err){
      throw err;
    }   
    html = data;  
  });
```

**I get the following error:**

```
Error: ENOENT, The system cannot find the file specified. '/view/index.html'
```

Can you see what's causing the error? I'm quite new to node.js.

Additional information:
I'm running Windows 7 64 bit, up to date version of node.exe.

**I've found the solution!**

When node.exe is run through cmd the default directory for node.exe is user.... that's where I was going wrong, it wa using a different directory to where the node.exe is located.

Comment: the path you specified is absolute, you should reference it relatively (`./view` rather than `/view`

Comment: i've tried ./ and /, both give the same error.

Comment: @JackBrown node.js is unstable on windows, it's a lot easier to learn node.js using 0.4.x on linix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things:

- You should resolved the relative path first to real path and try reading the file.
- Read the file asynchronously to get the callback
- Relative path should be corrected. The "./view/index.html" in my code is the path relative to where you start your node.js engine.

Rough code will be:

```
        // get real path from relative path
        fs.realpath('./view/index.html', function(err, resolvedPath) {
            // pass the resolved path to read asynchronously
            fs.readFile(resolvedPath, function(err, data) { 
                // assign the variable per your use case
                html = data;
            })
        });
```

Note that I am using version 4.11 (latest stable version)

Comment: When trying this approach I get a TypeError, 'first argument must be a string, Array or Buffer'.

Comment: Are you using 4.11? I could check if there is an API changes. You might want to check if your path is resolved first by printing the resolved path and check if there is any error in fs.realpath callback and proceed by checking the fs.readFile

Comment: @JackBrown `console.log(err, resolvedPath)`. That typeError means `resolvedPath` is probably `null` and you should check and read the error. `if (err) throw err;`

Comment: @Raynos I've tried to console.log(resolvedPath), but the error happens before I can log it to the console. http2.js: 602 throw new TypeError('first argument must be a string, Array or Buffer');

Comment: @Jack can you put up your updated code so we could check it out?

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna lose the Sync part. Only `readFile` when you have a callback.

Also: ./path, not /path.